# Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra: filling in some intermediate steps

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, rouches-theorem

I'm familiar with Rouche's theorem in the following form:

> If $f, g$ are analytic on a domain $\Omega$ with $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ on $\partial \Omega$, then $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros in $\Omega$.

I'm walking through how to use this to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra, but am stuck on how the "usual" lower bound is used and where it comes from. The argument goes something like this:

1. Suppose $p(z) = a_n z^n + \cdots + a_1 z + a_0$
2. Set $f(z) = a_n z^n$
3. Set $g(z) = a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 z + a_0$
4. Choose $R$ large enough such that

$$R > \max\left( {|a_{n-1}| + \cdots + |a_1| + |a_0| \over |a_n| }, 1\right)$$

5. Then $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ on the circle $|{z}|= R$, so apply Rouche and note that $z^n$ has $n$ zeros at $z_0 = 0$, which is in this region.

I am stuck on part 4: I buy that such an $R$ can be chosen, since these coefficients are fixed. What I can't work out is the explicit inequality that shows 4 $\implies$ 5.

The argument I'm looking for would essentially fill in the vdots in this chain of inequalities:

$$\begin{align*}
|g(z)| 
&:= |a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 z + a_0 | \\
&\leq |a_{n-1}z^{n-1}| + \cdots + |a_1 z| + |a_0 | \quad\text{by the triangle inequality} \\
&= |a_{n-1}|\cdot |z^{n-1}| + \cdots + |a_1|\cdot| z| + |a_0 | \\
& \quad\vdots \quad ? \\
&\leq |a_n z^n| \\
&:= |f(z)|
\end{align*}$$

I would prefer a proof that doesn't necessarily assume that $p$ is monic, since I'd like to trace $a_n$ throughout the inequality.

I would also welcome answers that show how you might run this problem backwards, i.e. writing out some inequalities in order to deduce what $R$ should be.

Comment: This was asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318813/inequality-for-polynomial-value-from-rudin/3318827#3318827

Comment: @OliverDiaz Not quite: I was mostly curious about this specific choice of $R$, which shows up in a few places and is (I think) a slightly lower bound than the one used in Rudin. But thank you for the reference!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inequality for polynomial value from Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318813/inequality-for-polynomial-value-from-rudin)

Comment: @Jan that appears to be the same question Oliver posted about in a comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
|a_{n-1}|\cdot |z^{n-1}| + \cdots + |a_1|\cdot| z| + |a_0 | 
&=  |a_{n-1}|\cdot R^{n-1} + \cdots + |a_1| R + |a_0 | \\
&\leq |a_{n-1}|\cdot R^{n-1}+|a_{n-2}|\cdot R^{n-1} + \cdots + |a_1| \cdot R^{n-1} + |a_0 |\cdot R^{n-1} \qquad\text{(1)}\\
&= R^{n-1} \left( |a_{n-1}| + |a_{n-2}| + \cdots + |a_1| + |a_0| \right) \\
&\leq R^{n-1} \left( |a_n|\cdot R \right) \qquad\text{(2)}\\
&= R^{n} |a_n|
\end{align*}
$$

In inequality (1) I have used the fact that $R^{i} \leq R^{n-1}$ for $0 \leq i \leq n-1$ and inequality (2) follows by choice of $R$.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was missing! Thank you!

Comment: Technically, inequality (2) is a strict inequality, $<,$ which is necessary by the given statement of Rouche's theorem.