# Missing detail FTA proof

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

In the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741902/987127, I don't see at which point there is a strict inequality, to satisfy Rouche's theorem.

Comment: In that answer, inequality $(2)$ is actually a strong inequality

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks!